# Testing custom hook and context async method with react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a hook that uses a context underneath

The hook looks like this

```
const useConfirmation = () => {
  const { openDialog } = useContext(ConfirmationContext);

  const getConfirmation = ({ ...options }: DialogParams) => new Promise((res) => {
    openDialog({ actionCallback: res, ...options });
  });

  return { getConfirmation };
};
```

`getConfirmation` returns a promise that is resolved if the dialog is confirmed or not.

```
export const ConfirmationProvider = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  const [dialogConfig, setDialogConfig] = useState<DialogConfig>(initialState);

  const openDialog = (config: DialogConfig) => {
    setDialogOpen(true);
    setDialogConfig(config);
  };

  const resetDialog = () => {
    setDialogOpen(false);
    setDialogConfig(initialState);
  };

  const onConfirm = () => {
    resetDialog();
    dialogConfig.actionCallback(true);
  };

  const onDismiss = () => {
    resetDialog();
    dialogConfig.actionCallback(false);
  };

  const value = useMemo(() => ({ openDialog }), []);

  ...
};
```

When is going to be used it simply gets called like:

```
// Confirmed is a boolean
const connfirmed = await getConfirmation({...});

// confirmed ? 'Confirmed' : 'Canceled'
```

I'm able to test that the dialog closes or open but never the value of the state inside the context, how can I test this?

Currently my test looks like this:

```
  it('should open a confirmation dialog', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useConfirmation(), {
      wrapper: ({ children }) => (
        <AllTheProviders>
          <ConfirmationProvider>{children}</ConfirmationProvider>
        </AllTheProviders>
      ),
    });

    const confirmed = act(() => {
      result.current.getConfirmation({
        title: 'Confirmation Message',
        text: 'Confirmation Text',
        confirmText: 'Confirm',
        confirmColor: 'var(--quo-pink)',
      });
    });

    const modal = getByRole(document.body, 'dialog');

    expect(modal).toBeInTheDocument();

    await user.click(getByRole(document.body, 'button', { name: 'Cancel' }));

    expect(modal).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

I want to be able to say that confirmed is expected `toBeTruthy` or `toBeFalsy` but as it is right now its always `{"then": [Function then]}`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you using `act`? And given you're getting a promise (or at least then-able) did you consider seeing what it resolves to?

Comment: I'm using act because the docs say that you need to use `act` to execute methods that modify state inside a context, if you don't use it there is even a warning.

In the app the promise resolves to `true` or `false`. Thats what I'm trying to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response was very straight forward. I simply needed to assign the return value to a variable outside.

```
...
let confirmed;

act(() => {
 confirmed = result.current.getConfirmation({
    title: 'Confirmation Message',
    text: 'Confirmation Text',
    confirmText: 'Confirm',
    confirmColor: 'var(--quo-pink)',
 });
});

expect(modal).toBeInTheDocument();

await user.click(getByRole(document.body, 'button', { name: 'Cancel' }));
await expect(confirmed).resolves.toBe(true);
...
```